# This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

model `ProductFilter` has `products` `ManyToManyField`. I need to get attribute `to_export` from `product.filters` of the highest priority (`ProductFilter.priority` field)

I figured out this

```py
filters = ProductFilter.objects.filter(
    products__in=[OuterRef('pk')]
).order_by('priority')

Product.objects.annotate(
    filter_to_export=Subquery(filters.values('to_export')[:1])
)
```

But it raises

> ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but anyway:

Looks like the related lookup cannot handle `OuterRef` here: `products__in=[OuterRef('pk')]`

Note: In Django 3.2 the OP's example yields a different error, viz. `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got ResolvedOuterRef(pk).`

As there's only one `pk` value here, I don't think you need to use the `__in` lookup.

The following seems to work, although I'm not sure if it's exactly what the OP wants:

```py
filters = ProductFilter.objects.filter(
    products=OuterRef('pk')  # replaced products__in lookup
).order_by('priority')

products = Product.objects.annotate(
    filter_to_export=Subquery(filters.values('to_export')[:1])
)
```

The resulting SQL (slightly simplified table names):

```sql
SELECT "product"."id", (
    SELECT U0."to_export" 
    FROM "productfilter" U0 
    INNER JOIN "productfilter_products" U1 
    ON (U0."id" = U1."productfilter_id") 
    WHERE U1."product_id" = "product"."id" 
    ORDER BY U0."priority" DESC LIMIT 1
) AS "filter_to_export" 
FROM "product"
```